# Could XMLHttpRequest be called from client across domain or only to same domain?

Tags: javascript

XMLHttpRequest cannot be called across domain as "modern browsers do not allow access across domains" (W3Schools). XMLHttpRequest could be used from client to server at the same domain but cannot be used from client to a server across domain? And so, normally XMLHttpRequest supposed to be requested if resource and client are on same domain? But could it be actually called across domain if called from one server to another? Like if it called from node.js server to other server?

Comment: XHRs *can* be used cross-origin, provided the server agrees by sending the appropriate CORS headers. Requesting from an HTTP client makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, It seemed XMLHttpRequest is no use unless it's teamed with server CORS headers, which is not so common practice? I'm studying basics and it's strange why do they use XMLHttpRequest as an classic  example of a request widely if it is not so common to use in practice? Confusing.

Comment: CORS *is* common practice, and XHRs (or `fetch` nowadays) are extremely widespread and at the core of every single-page application. I think you are confused about HTTP and what constitutes a client and a server.

Comment: Aha, good to know. That was my question (if XHR is in common use in cross). So many good tutorials, but not mentioning about this.

Comment: (not even mentioning about that is possible and common to overcome with CORS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

**Cross-origin restrictions do not allow you to communicate across ports without sending a Access-Control-Allow-Origin** Well, that's the problem.

A better solution would be to use ***Nginx*** or some other webserver to reverse proxy those two running applications to the same domain and port.

Comment: "a better solution" is arguable and sometimes not an option.